# Is it possible to compute derivative of truncated SVD without computing a full SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, svd

I am working with derivatives of the SVD. My setting is the following:

Let $A:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $t\mapsto A(t)$ be a differentiable matrix-valued function, $m \leq n$. Assume that  $\mathrm{rank}\,A(t)=m$ and the singular values $\sigma_1(t),\dotsc,\sigma_m(t)$ satisfy $\sigma_1(t)>\dotsb>\sigma_m(t)$ for all $t$.

Now we look at the "economy-size" SVD
$$A(t)=U(t)\varSigma(t)V(t)^\mathrm{T},$$
$U(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $\varSigma(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $V(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. By construction, this decomposition is unique up to a simultaneous change of sings in a column of $U(t)$ and the corresponding column of $V(t)$. Using the product rule, we get
$$\dot{A}(t)=\dot{U}(t)\varSigma(t)V(t)^\mathrm{T}
+U(t)\dot{\varSigma}(t)V(t)^\mathrm{T}
+U(t)\varSigma(t)\dot{V}(t)^\mathrm{T},$$
where the dot denotes the derivative with respect to $t$.

These two papers discuss the calculation of the matrices $\dot{U}(t)$, $\dot{\varSigma}(t)$ and $\dot{V}(t)$:

http://www.ics.forth.gr/_publications/2000_eccv_SVD_jacobian.pdf (Section 2)

http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/files/NA-08-01.pdf (Section 3.2)

Both papers describe how these matrices can be obtained form the SVD $A(t)=U(t)\varSigma(t)V(t)^\mathrm{T}$ and the derivative $\dot{A}(t)$.

However, I am not interested in a full SVD, but in a truncated SVD, using only the $r$ dominant singular values and corresponding singular vectors, and in its derivative. I would like to avoid computing a full SVD of $A(t)$ and to compute the derivatives only using a truncated SVD. The methods described in the two papers above can be easily modified to compute the first $r$ diagonal entries of $\dot{\varSigma}(t)$ only using a truncated SVD. However, this does not work for the dominant singular vectors.

Does anyone know a method for computing the variations of the dominant singular vectors without computing the full SVD? I have come to believe this might be impossible because we need the information from the variation in the non-dominant singular vectors to compute these derivatives but I could not find a proof for this, either. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What assumptions do you use to show that the singular values are differentiable? Usually one needs some sort of uniqueness sort of thing, otherwise you are dealing with generalised gradients (as in non smooth calculus).

Comment: The singular values are bounded from each other ($\sigma_1(t)>\dotsb>\sigma_m(t)$ for all $t$), so no non-uniqueness issues should occur.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you got the answer you wanted but this paper might answer the question:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08521

It is shown that the truncated SVD of order $r$ is differentiable at a matrix $R$ if the singular values of order $r$ and $r+1$ are distinct and the formula for the derivative is given.